# How to copy unique files to each directory using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have lot of files in source directory with different name and ending with some number as suffix name. I need to copy all the files into 3 different directory. While copying, each file should be unique to other directory.

Example :

```
       Source directory 
           1) Test01.csv
           2) Test02.csv
           3) Test03.csv
           4) Nontesting01.csv
           5) Nontesting02.csv
           6) Nontesting03.csv

      Destination directory
         Directory 1 : Test01.csv
                       Nontesting01.csv
         Directory 2 : Test02.csv
                       Nontesting02.csv
         Directory 3 : Test03.csv
                       Nontesting03.csv
```

I have tried below code but it's copying 1 file per directory.

```
       #!/bin/bash

   dest=/Users/myprofile/Testing_
   count=0
   for f in *.csv ; do (cp $f/*.csv* "${dest}"${count}/$f ) ; 
   ((count++))
   done
```

Could someone help how to achieve this scenario using shell scripting.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: `cp 'Source directory'/*01.csv 'Destination directory/Directory 1/'` etc...?

Comment: Sure Cyrus i will add my tried code as well

Comment: Ya i can try this code..thanks Fravadona

Comment: Assuming that the source directory contains a file named `foo.bar` , it is not clear to me which destination directory it should be copied into.

Comment: In my source directory, i have have lot of different files. Example foo.bar1, foo.bar2, bar.foo1 & bar.foo2 . So my requirement i need to copy files which is ending with 1 as suffix name should move to usr/myDirectory1/ and files ending with 2  as suffix name should move to usr/Directory2/

Comment: `files1=(*.bar1); files2=(*.bar2); cp -v -- "${files1[@]}" /usr/myDirectory1; cp -v -- "${files2[@]}" /usr/myDirectory2` , enjoy...

Comment: Are there only 3 directories (i.e. only 01, 02 and 03) in the filenames?  Since the digits are prefixed with a 0, I would guess you have 01 through 99...?

Comment: Yeah i have three directories only.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing on what **Jetchisel** said, the code should be adapted, as a loop on patterns, to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

destPref="/Users/myprofile/Testing_"

for pattern in 01 02 03
do
    files=(*${pattern}.csv) 
    cp -v -- "${files[@]}" "${destPref}${pattern}/"
done
```

As a general guidance, if you start by writing the code logic

- in pseudo-code,
- fine-grained for each task that you are trying to accomplish,
- in the correct sequence and
- in the correct context,

then having that worded so that it does exactly what you want it to do ... will, *almost explicitly*, tell you **WHAT** you need to code for each of those, not the **HOW**. The **HOW** is the nitty gritty of coding.

If you give that a try, the solution will almost pop out of the page at you.

Good luck with your apprenticeship!

Comment: Sure thanks for your code. i will check and confirm you.